# JRebel to monitor struts.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, jrebel

Couldn't find any info regarding this. Is there any way that JRebel monitor struts.xml for changes. This is changed alot when testing.

Any solution?

**EDITED**

**Console**

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30

[2012-09-22 19:29:45] JRebel: Directory 'C:\MyProjects\4-Interceptors\target\classes' will be monitored for changes.
[2012-09-22 19:29:45] JRebel: Directory 'C:\MyProjects\4-Interceptors\src\main\webapp' will be monitored for changes.

[2012-09-22 19:29:50] JRebel-Log4j: Monitoring Log4j configuration in 'file:/C:/MyProjects/4-Interceptors/target/classes/log4j.properties'.
```

**Rebel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="C:/MyProjects/4-Interceptors/target/classes">
        </dir>
    </classpath>

    <web>
        <link target="/">
            <dir name="C:/MyProjects/4-Interceptors/src/main/webapp">
            </dir>
        </link>
    </web>

</application>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

just add `rebel.xml` to the projects `resource` folder in the project folder. It will automatically detect every changes in `struts.xml`.

**NOTE::** jrebel is not dependent on frameworks.

Comment: I tried that but rebel is not monitoring struts.xml. I have maven project and struts.xml is in resource folder. log4j.properties is also there and its monitored but no struts.xml

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Struts do you use? And what is the change you have introduced to the file? Perhaps this is something that isn't implemented yet. The best you can do is to provide a sample app and send your problem description to JRebel support

Comment: This is simple test project. I have added more information in the question. Please see above in edited section. Thanks

Comment: Struts2 latest version. I don't know what to change to introduce struts.xml file to be monitored.

Comment: How do you know it is not being monitored? For that you would have to change something in struts.xml, right? So, what kind of changed did you do to struts.xml?

Comment: like  changing result to different page. Changes in action name etc. Many changes from which you know struts.xml changes are not reflected.